# PyDev in Eclipse seems not supporting incremental find

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Eclipse Galileo + PyDev 1.5.4

Looks like under PyDev environment, the incremental find is not working. Can anyone confirm this, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Helios + PyDev Nightly from a few days ago. Working normally. I guess it's a feature of the generic text editor so it should work no matter which environment you use. Try the newest PyDev version (add http://pydev.org/nightly as update site) or a fresh Eclipse installation/workspace. If it still doesn't work, file a bug report.

BTW did you look at [this similar bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=149927)?